# How to: Make addition to class property within list

Tags: java, list, class

I have a `List<Presenter> presenterList;`

With

```
public class Presenter(){
  String name;
  String imageRef; // Filename to be downloaded
  Bitmap image;

  (etc...)
}
```

I'm working with AsyncTask & once the image has downloaded, I wish to go through the list and set Image value to the newly download image.
so far i have

```
Presenter pres = PresenterList.get(Position);
pres.Image = new (Bitmap) downloadedImageFromImageRef;
```

however i fear that this will not relate to the Image value of the presenter within the list.

How do i refer, or even assign to the specific Presenter attribute within the list?

From working with C (many years ago), i belive somthing like a pointer to the value in which to assign .Image would work

Thank you in advace

Comment: It is unclear how you want to relate the image to a presenter, is it through the name, or you are simply affecting always to last presenter in list, or in sequence from beginning or ... ?

Comment: my mistake. a property called, imageref is used which stores the actual image file name that needs to be downloaded.
there are 2 stages, downloading the data for name, imageref & description. then downloading the image from the imageref value and storing the bitmap to the image value. i will make the edit. thank you

Comment: i am working through the list<Presenter> iteratively

Comment: Minor note: it is bad style (and confusing for other Java developers) to start variables with Uppercase characters (Pascal casing). That casing is used for classes/interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you have C experience, then the thing to know about Java is that it doesn't use pointers, but it does use references. So if I'm understanding your problem correctly, you are already using the `Image` attribute of a `Presenter` instance elsewhere and then you want to fill it in later. Assigning `pres.Image = new (Bitmap) DownloadedImageFromImageRef;` would not work in this case because other objects are looking at a different `Bitmap` object reference.

What you might need to do is use an observer pattern -- it depends on the details of your problem. Here's an example:

Somewhere in the code I have a class `Foo` that wants to use the `Image` property from a `Presenter` instance. But, since that property isn't set until later, this class wants to be notified when it is ready (it is an observer).

```
public class Presenter {
  String Name;
  String ImageRef; // Filename to be downloaded
  private Bitmap Image;

  private PresenterImageObserver observer;

  public void setImageObeserver(PresenterImageObserver pio) {
    this.observer = pio;
  }

  public void setImage(Bitmap b) {
    this.Image = b;
    this.observer.imageLoaded(b);
  }
}

public interface PresenterImageObserver {
  public void imageLoaded(Bitmap b);
}

public class Foo implements PresenterImageObserver {
  //Foo's constructor. It wants the image from presenter p, when it is ready
  public Foo(Presenter p) {
    p.setImageObserver(this);
  }

  public void imageLoaded(Bitmap b) {
    //b contains the loaded image and this Foo instance can use it now!
  }
}
```

You'd need to set the image using `pres.setImage(new (Bitmap) downloadedImageFromImageRef);`.

Answer (score 1):

So you have to find in your list the `Presenter` for which the correct imageref. You have basically two options.

First, you simply iterate through your list

```
for (Presenter presenter: presenterList) {
    if (presenter.imageref.equals(imageName) {
        Presenter.image = new Bitmap(downloadedImage);
        break; // found : stop iterations
    }
}
```

Secondly, you can create a `HashMap` for your presenters, with the imageref as the key :

```
HashMap<String, Presenter> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Presenter presenter: presenterList) {
    map.put(presenter.imageref, presenter);
}
```

Then, you can directly find the right presenter through `map.get(imageName)`